# REGEX: getting value of src="" SPECIAL CHARACTERS

Tags: java, regex

Here's my regex code

```
(?i)\\s*src\\s*=\\s*(?:\"[^\"]*(?<!\\.css|\\.ico)\"|'[^']*(?<!\\.css|\\.ico)'|[^'\">\\s]+(?<!\\.css|\\.ico))
```

i want to get all the value inside of src="" then change it to what the business whats.. something like this..

```
Pattern src = Pattern.compile(HTML_IMG_SRC);
        Matcher srcM = src.matcher(getNewLine());
        setNewLine(srcM.replaceAll(" src=\"images"));
```

the value inside of src is ... src="../images"
i want to omit the ../

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to replace `src="../images...` to `src="images...`. This is how you can do that:

```
    String str = "asdf='jkl' src=\"../images/example.jpg\" asrc='../images/as' src='../images/example.png'";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\\ssrc=['\"])../(images)", "$1$2"));
```

Explanation:

- `\\ssrc` will make sure that you check indeed the src attributes, as it starts with whitespace. I.e. asrc attribute will be omitted.

  - You need two backslashes so one esapces the other, so the resulting regex will be `\ssrc`
- The character class `['\"]` makes sure that you can match both `src="..."` and `src='...'`

  - You need to escape the double quotes to make the java string valid. Your regex will be `['"]`
- You need the parentheses to capture the exact quote you found on the string. Then we refer to them with the backreferences `$1` and `$2`.
- The easiest java code to run this regex is `String.replaceAll`. It's like the usual `replace`, except that it evaluates the strings as regexes.
- This code won't check if the src is an actual image, like `.png` or `.jpg`. There are some tricks to do that too.

Comment: Thanks Tamas for these great info. :)

Answer (score 0):

So if your getNewLine() returns for example 'blah src="../images" blah' you would like to get 'blah src="images" blah', right?